# System timer c#

Tags: c#, timer, system

I have some code involving a system timer that starts counting in seconds when a file is added to a folder then stops when it is removed.  when the timer is stopped is shows the correct time however when I restart the timer  it picks up where it left off instead of restarting at 0. Here is my code..

```
        t2 = new System.Timers.Timer();
        t2.AutoReset = true;
        t2.Interval = 1000;
        t2.Elapsed += OnTimeEvent2;
        watch();

    }
    private void OnTimeEvent2(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {

            s += 1;

            lblSeconds.Text = string.Format(s.ToString());

        }));
    }
```

Comment: Are you expecting `s` to go back to 0? If so, that would require you actually *setting* `s` to 0 when you stop (or start) the timer. Do you?

Comment: This approach, incrementing a counter, will be very inaccurate for longer periods of time.  Use the [Stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) class instead, and simply update the label with the elapsed time in the timer event.

Comment: I am new to timers and am unsure how to implement the stopwatch class.  Could you give me a sample to work with?

Comment: Yes the idea was to set s back to zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the System.Windows.Forms.Timer so you don't need to worry about cross-threading.  Here's a quick example of using the Stopwatch class:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Timer tmr = new Timer();
private System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tmr.Interval = 1000;
    tmr.Tick += Tmr_Tick;
    tmr.Start();
    sw.Start();
}

private void Tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblSeconds.Text = ((int)sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds).ToString();
}
```

To make the timer start from zero again, simply use the Restart() method:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sw.Restart();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do something else to prevent many timers from running:
When a file is created register the DateTime somewhere and put a [filesystemwatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) on the file.

..then on the watchers deleted event get the DateTime once more and compare them.

In fact, if you're just monitoring a folder for the appearance adn disappearance of a specific file the filesystemwatcher can help you detect both events.

Else remember to reste your counter manually when you detect the file deletion.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `DispatcherTimer` instead. That way you don't need to invoke on the GUI thread manually. Also, it will reset on `Stop/Start`.

Comment: This looks like winforms question and it's not about restart timer, but about resetting the value displayed by the timer in `Label`.

Comment: Yes that is what I am attempting to do,  When the timer is stopped I have a method to grab the value of the label then reset it to zero then start again when a new file hits the folder I was using the timer from the toolbox but it would start counting rapidly instead of staying at a normal pace.